# How can I properly bring data from api?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

```
import React from "react";
import noviceImg from "./resources/kull.jpg";
import female1 from "./resources/f1.png";
import female2 from "./resources/f2.png";
import male1 from "./resources/m1.png";
import male2 from "./resources/m2.png";
import kendi from "./resources/kendi.png";
import styles from "./Personel.module.css";
import {
  Header,
  Subheader,
  Content,
  kendisi
} from "./components/Personelcomponents";
import { MdBorderColor } from "react-icons/md";
import { pink } from "@material-ui/core/colors";
import Navbar from "../../components/Navbar/Navbar";
import useWindowSize from "../../hooks/useWindowSize";
import Not from "./Not";
import { Container } from "@material-ui/core";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

var DataisLoaded = false;

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  kimlikId: state?.account?.principal?.kimlikId,
  sonucList: state?.account?.principal?.sonucList,
  DataisLoaded: true
});

const Personel = ({ sonucList }) => {
  if (!DataisLoaded)
    return (
      <div>
        <h1> Pleses wait some time.... </h1>{" "}
      </div>
    );

  return (
    <div className={styles.root}>
      <Navbar className={styles.navBar} />
      <Not className={styles.not} />
      <Content>
        <div className={styles.card_k}>
          <img alt="" src={kendi} />
          <b>
            <h4 className={styles.name}>İSİM</h4>
          </b>
          <p className={styles.cardtext}>
            <br />
            Baba Adı:
            <br />
            Yakınlık Derecesi: Kendisi
            <br />
            <div>
              <button_k type="button">Randevu Al</button_k>
            </div>
            <div></div>
            <br />
          </p>
        </div>

        <div className={styles.card_f}>
          <img alt="" src={female1} />
          <h4 className={styles.name}>İSİM</h4>
          <p class="card-text">
            Ana Adı:{sonucList.sonucList[0].bireyAd}
            <br />
            Baba Adı:
            <br />
            Yakınlık Derecesi:
            <br />
            <button type="button">Randevu Al</button>
            <div></div>
            <br />
          </p>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.card_f}>
          <img alt="" src={female1} />
          <h4 className={styles.name}>İSİM</h4>
          <p class="card-text">
            Ana Adı:
            <br />
            Baba Adı:
            <br />
            Yakınlık Derecesi:
            <br />
            <button type="button">Randevu Al</button>
            <div></div>
            <br />
          </p>
        </div>

        <div className={styles.card_m}>
          <img alt="" src={male2} />
          <h4 className={styles.name}>İSİM</h4>
          <p class="card-text">
            Ana Adı:
            <br />
            Baba Adı:
            <br />
            Yakınlık Derecesi:
            <br />
            <div>
              <button_m type="button">Randevu Al</button_m>
            </div>
            <div></div>
            <br />
          </p>
        </div>

        <div className={styles.characterBox}>
          <h2>Sorceress</h2>
          <img alt="" src={noviceImg} />
        </div>
        <div className={styles.characterBox}>
          <h2>Sorceress</h2>
          <img alt="" src={noviceImg} />
        </div>
        <div className={styles.characterBox}>
          <h2>Sorceress</h2>
          <img alt="" src={noviceImg} />
        </div>
      </Content>
    </div>
  );
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Personel);
```

Sorry for the messy code. I'm kinda new to react and js and trying to bring some data from api but I have no idea what I'm doing really. I'm trying to copy other pages in project and they used mapStateProps and somehow I can bring my data (Sonuclist and KimlikId) from there but the problem is it page loaded without data and cause error. (After then it brings data from api and works normally) to prevent that I used if statement and DataisLoaded check but it doesn't return after the first if. Tried using states but apperantly you can do those in class comp only?

I'm trying to copy other pages in project and they used mapStateProps and somehow I can bring my data (Sonuclist and KimlikId) from there but the problem is it page loaded without data and cause error. (After then it brings data from api and works normally) to prevent that I used if statement and DataisLoaded check but it doesn't return after the first if.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would suggest using `useSelector` instead of `mapStateToProps`.

I have not seen this approach before. `mapStateToProps` is (was) used in class components. For functional components we have the `useSelector` hook which does the exact same thing as `mapStateToProps` (well, without out of the box memoization, but that's out of this context).

It is highly recommended to use the hook, so I suggest you give it a try :)

**Now, back to the issue:**

I don't see how this can work at **any point in time** as it looks like you don't use `DataisLoaded` from your props, it is a completely different variable that has nothing to do with the actual store.

Try deleting `var DataisLoaded = false;` and do something like:

`const Personel = ({ sonucList, DataisLoaded }) => {`

Remember that data from your store will only be available this way. Nevertheless I still highly suggest you give `useSelector` a try.

Hope this helps :)

https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector

Comment: Thank you I tried useSelector and looks like it works too but I still couldn't make it work. Problem is function goes api after it's returned and it doesn't seem to refresh after it connects api.